# Unable to upgrade Scipy using PIP

Tags: python, ubuntu, scipy, pip

I try to upgrade Scipy using PIP on Ubuntu 16.04 but always receive this error. I'm not sure what is going on. The progress reaches 99% and then stops, and spits out this error.

I've tried upgrading pip but the same error still occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 310, in run
wb.build(autobuilding=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 750, in build
self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 370, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 587, in _prepare_file
session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 810, in unpack_url
hashes=hashes
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 649, in unpack_http_url
hashes)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 871, in _download_http_url
_download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 595, in _download_url
hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/hashes.py", line 46, in check_against_chunks
for chunk in chunks:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 563, in written_chunks
for chunk in chunks:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/ui.py", line 139, in iter
for x in it:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 552, in resp_read
decode_content=False):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 353, in stream
data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 310, in read
data = self._fp.read(amt)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 54, in read
self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 275, in cache_response
self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 87, in dumps
).encode("utf8"),
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to disable the cache during install using

```
pip install --no-cache-dir packageName
```

where packageName is `scipy` in this case

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked perfectly! I'll accept the answer once it lets me :)

Answer (score 0):

The last line says "MemoryError"
Are you using a virtual environment?

If so, the environment probably requires more memory to be allocated to it.

Go to Player > Manage > Virtual Machine Settings

Here, drag the slider to choose a higher value of memory to be allocated.

Restart the virtual environment for the changes to take place.

I hope this helps!